# Using Glade 3.12 widgets in python

Tags: python, pygtk, glade

Just as some history, I have been using python for about 5 years now and have finally decided to make my first gui app in Glade.

I started with something basic, I have a button, a Gtkentry and  gtktextview
This is what I am trying to accomplish:

on button press, take from the text from gtk.entry and have it appended to the gtk.textview

now the main problem I have is that I can not find descent documentation for how to use the widgets, and the examples I find on the Internet reference both a builder variation as well as another variation of glade project which I can only assume has been discontinued. I would like to learn how builder fits into the python / glade collaboration.

my code so far:

```
import gtk
import pygtk

def onDeleteWindow(self, *args):
    Gtk.main_quit(*args)

def hello(button):
    text_buffer.set_text(txtinput.get_text())



builder = gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("dagui.glade")

handlers = {
    "onDeleteWindow": gtk.main_quit,
    "buttondown": hello
}
builder.connect_signals(handlers)

textarea = builder.get_object("textview1")
window = builder.get_object("window1")
txtinput = builder.get_object("entry1")
window.show_all()

gtk.main()
window.show_all()

gtk.main()
```

now this all works and pressing the button will print what ever is in the gtk.entry but I can not find how to append it to the textview. I also am not sure what to search for to find documentation, I tried "gtk builder gtk.textview" and pygtk build gtk.textview append" and all other variations.

Though knowing how to simply add the text to the text view would be great, having a link to somewhere where I can get in plain english how to use these widgets I would be forever great-full.

Answer (score 1):

Frob the [`gtk.TextView`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktextview.html), you need to get the [`gtk.TextBuffer`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktextbuffer.html) by using the textview's `buffer` property.

From the textbuffer, you need to get the iterator that points to the end of the buffer with the [`get_end_iter`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktextbuffer.html#method-gtktextbuffer--get-end-iter) method. With that iterator, and your text, you can use the textbuffer's [`insert`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktextbuffer.html#method-gtktextbuffer--insert) method.

**Edit:** Since I don't have the `dagui.glade` file, I couldn't test it, but see the following code:

```
def hello(button):
    global textarea, txtinput
    buffer = textarea.get_property('buffer')
    i = buffer.get_end_iter()
    buffer.insert(i, txtinput.get_text())
    # clear the input window after appending the text
    txtinput.set_text('')
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I have found out the the gtk.textview.get_buffer actually sets the buffer ID and then the textview.set_text(buffer) isall I needed.

here is the full working code, the glade is just a button, an entry and a textview:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
import gtk
import pygtk

def onDeleteWindow(self, *args):
    Gtk.main_quit(*args)

def hello(button):
    textbuffer = textarea.get_buffer()
    textbuffer.set_text(txtinput.get_text())



builder = gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("dagui.glade")

handlers = {
    "onDeleteWindow": gtk.main_quit,
    "buttondown": hello
}
builder.connect_signals(handlers)

textarea = builder.get_object("textview1")
window = builder.get_object("window1")
txtinput = builder.get_object("entry1")
window.show_all()


gtk.main()
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this to add text :

```
textarea.set_text('whatever you want')
```

and this for adding pango markup ( http://goo.gl/94Pkk ) :

```
textarea.set_markup('<span size="large>Example</span>')
```

Here's the documentation : http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: A `gtk.TextView` doesn't have a `set_text` method, AFAICT.

Comment: Roland is correct, I have verified that it does not:
AttributeError: 'gtk.TextView' object has no attribute 'set_text'